# Can one reject suggested (by others) edits to one's own post?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I recently edited this question: [Improve auto-generated subtitles/CC for Youtube videos that are not mine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95787/117311)

I later found out it was rejected, although I thought it was a solid edit (similar to numerous others on the site). Curious to learn why so as to correct my mistakes I looked for the [reasoning behind the rejection](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76929):

What first caught my eye was the fact that in spite of the fact that only **one user had reviewed** the edit, the **rejection was validated**.
Puzzled as I was, I found out that **the one and only person rejecting the edit was the writer of the question as well**.
To wrap the whole thing up, when one takes a closer look, one can notice that the user is so far awarded on this site **with a reputation of 181**.

[image: just one reviewer]

As per [site rules](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit):

> Privilege Type: Moderation Privilege
>   **Awarded At: 2,000 Reputation**
>
> #### What is edit questions and answers?
>
> We believe in the power of community editing. That means once you've generated enough reputation, we trust you to edit *anything* in the system without it going through peer review. Not just your posts- *anyone's posts!*
>   ......
>
> #### Reviewing suggested edits
>
> In addition, **users with this privilege level can also begin reviewing suggested edits (which previously you would have had to suggest)**. These edits remain in a pending state until they get enough votes to either approve them and make the edits take effect or reject them and discard the edit. **Two votes in either direction will finalize the action**, except on Stack Overflow where three votes are required.

So, regardless of whether "*my edit*" should be rejected or not:

**Can someone reject suggested (by others) edits to his/her own post without even having the necessary reputation points and without the given assent of a second user (peer)**?

If so, what is the point of the following message:

> Thanks for your edit!
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

Comment: This MSE post covers the vast majority of the rationale in favor of allowing this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251284/should-a-question-author-be-allowed-to-be-the-only-reviewer-and-reject-a-suggest/251288#251288

Comment: @jonsca That is great. The post most certainly clarifies most of my questions. I just think that a similar one was present on this site as well. Nothing came up when I was looking for answers before posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author is also allowed to review suggested edits to their post, and their vote is binding, either for or against.

That's not to say that someone else couldn't come along and edit the post later (especially if they have full edit privileges). But the thinking is that the original author knows more than most whether a suggested edit is a good one or not.

As for

> Thanks for your edit!
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

That just means that when you look at a post where you have a suggested edit pending, only you will see the post as you've edited it. If they suggested edit is approved, then the changes will be applied and everyone will see the post that way; if rejected then you'll see the message as it was.

See also:

- [Why can any user edit any other user's question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120576/21960)
- [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474/21960)

Comment: Couple of points. "_The author is also allowed..._": I think this should be added on the sites [help pages](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) to avoid possible future misunderstandings by other users. "_That's not to say that someone else..._": I believe when a writer feels very strong -almost opinionated- of ones own writings, should be left in peace.  "_As for Thanks for your edit!_...": I understand the meaning of it. I just find it defies its purpose when one is not informed of the logic behind the above mentioned facts.

Comment: If you want improvements to the help pages, you should make a [feature-request] at [meta.se].

Comment: Part of the deal of posting on Stack Exchange is that others can (and do) edit what you post. It's all part of the "deal". It's even discussed in the [Help Center](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/editing). An author who disagrees with others attempts to improve the readability of their posts (so that they help as many people as possible) is likely to get downvotes as a result and, if they roll back the changes often enough, are bound to get a timed suspension for participating in an edit war. If someone doesn't want their stuff edited, they shouldn't post it here.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your answer and the points I made Al E. One last thing. From your comment I understand that all decision making about sites' Help Pages come from the main site. Correct? So it would affect all sites? By the way, how do you feel -considering your experience- about my suggestion?

Comment: For the most part, the help pages for all Stack Exchange sites is the same. There's some customization, such as in `/help/on-topic` as well as for specialized things, such as the sites that support LaTeX.